# How to update an Android Itemized overlay which is displayed on a map

Tags: android, dictionary, location, overlay

I have a custom overlay which should move around as the user (player) moves around. But the way I have it right now it just keeps adding more and more overlays making the icon have a trailing effect.

I attempted to remove the overlay on each location update but it appears to not be removing it. Though, I'm not sure if actually removing it is the correct way to accomplish what I'm trying to do. Is there a way to just update the location and refresh the map?

```
    public void drawMeOnMap()
{
    MapView mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
    mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
    drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.p18);
    itemizedOverlay = new IOverlay(drawable);

    if (mapOverlays.contains(itemizedOverlay))
    {
        mapOverlays.remove(itemizedOverlay);
    }

    GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint((int)(1E6*player.latitude), (int)(1E6*player.longitude));
    OverlayItem item = new OverlayItem(point, "", "");
    itemizedOverlay.addOverlay(item);
    mapOverlays.add(itemizedOverlay);
}
```

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have any outstanding examples of location applications using MyLocationOverlay--The one I found wasn't too useful and as you can see I don't really fully understand it.

--You know what, I must have been brain-fried staring at the problem too long, First three results on Google look promising.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Why don't you just use [MyLocationOverlay](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/com/google/android/maps/MyLocationOverlay.html)? It will do this all for you. Just make sure to call `disableMyLocation()` in onPause.

```
MyLocationOverlay myLocationOverlay = new MyLocationOverlay(this, mapView);
mapView.getOverlays().add(myLocationOverlay);
myLocationOverlay.enableMyLocation();
```

In any case you don't need to get the Mapview, mapOverlays, drawable, and create a new itemizedOverlay each time. That should only be done once in your onCreate or whatever. What you should do is just update the OverlayItem when the location changes and then call mapView.invalidate() to redraw the view.

```
GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint((int)(1E6*player.latitude), (int)(1E6*player.longitude));
OverlayItem item = new OverlayItem(point, "", "");
itemizedOverlay.clear();
itemizedOverlay.addOVerlay(item);
mapView.invalidate();
```

Comment: I wasn't aware of MyLocationOverlay when I started. I saw an example with itemizedOverlay somewhere and used that. I should be able to turn it over into MyLocationOverlay with the Itemized version easily?

Comment: Does MyLocationOverlay let you use custom images for the marker?
The app will have players (one is you) and the rest are put on the map via downloading locations from server.

Comment: No but you could override the drawMyLocation() method to use your own drawable.

Comment: You're still going to call and create an ItemizedOverlay at least once and that is where you will set your map pin from drawables. I am not sure, but you may need an ItemizedOverlay for each "player" if the graphics (map pin) are different. You will have to make sure you're updating and redrawing the correct overlay in this case.